TikZ: How to align both baseline=(label.base) and minimum height
I'm trying to create a custom section with the titlesec package using TikZ. The problem is that I can either get the minimum height of the rectangle aligned:

Or implement baseline=(label.base) which solves the above issue of incorrectly aligned text, but instead raises a problem with the minimum height of the rectangle:

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec, tikz}

% Custom section using the titlesec package
\titleformat{\section} % command level 
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % Format (current is the standard)
{\Sectitle\thesection} % Label (standard is numbering, denoted by \thesection)
{-0.4em} % Distance of label from text (standard is 1em)
{\Sectitle} % Code after (empty by standard)

\newcommand{\Sectitle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(label.base)]
    \node[rectangle, left color=blue!50!white, right color=blue, inner xsep = 8pt, inner ysep = 5pt, text = white, minimum height=0.8cm] (label) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Beautiful sections}

\section{Section spacing}

\end{document}

Does anyone know how I can correctly align the text and have the rectangles of equal height simultaneously?

"Section spacing" has letters with descender, not "Beautiful sections". To harmonize their positions inside the nodes you could add a \strut. Use then
\newcommand{\Sectitle}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, left color=blue!50!white, right color=blue, inner xsep = 8pt, inner ysep = 5pt, text = white]
    (label) {\strut #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

Note that, here, you don't need minimum height.
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec, tikz}

% Custom section using the titlesec package
\titleformat{\section} % command level
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % Format (current is the standard)
    {\Sectitle\thesection} % Label (standard is numbering, denoted by \thesection)
    {-0.4em} % Distance of label from text (standard is 1em)
    {\Sectitle} % Code after (empty by standard)

\newcommand{\Sectitle}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, left color=blue!50!white, right color=blue, inner xsep = 8pt, inner ysep = 5pt, text = white]
    (label) {\strut #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Beautiful sections}

\section{Section spacing}

\end{document}


Alternatively, you can use \smash and fix text height and text depth
\newcommand{\Sectitle}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      rectangle,
      left color=blue!50!white,
      right color=blue,
      inner xsep = 8pt,
      inner ysep = 5pt,
      text = white,
      text height=1em,
      text depth=1ex
    ]
    (label) {\smash{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec, tikz}

% Custom section using the titlesec package
\titleformat{\section} % command level
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % Format (current is the standard)
    {\Sectitle\thesection} % Label (standard is numbering, denoted by \thesection)
    {-0.4em} % Distance of label from text (standard is 1em)
    {\Sectitle} % Code after (empty by standard)

\newcommand{\Sectitle}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      rectangle,
      left color=blue!50!white,
      right color=blue,
      inner xsep = 8pt,
      inner ysep = 5pt,
      text = white,
      text height=1em,
      text depth=1ex
    ]
    (label) {\smash{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Beautiful sections}

\section{Section spacing}

\end{document}



Woow, you really hit 2 birds with 1 stone with the \strut command, effectively removing both the need for [baseline = (label.base)] along with minimum height! How come \strut is such a simple, yet powerful command, effectively able to replace both of the tikz commands? Are there any drawbacks to its usage, or is it really just the most practical solution for my problem?

@Atex \strut is a zero width box of 0.7\baselineskip height and 0.3\baselineskip depth. It's the expected line total height. Maybe if you use special characters like É orÄ (with accents), it would be too short. Then replace \strut with \vphantom{\strut É}.

Playing around a bit, I did notice that \strut does change how inner ysep behaves, but it makes sense now that you've explained what \strut does. I'm assuming it's because the inner ysep now measures from the little vertical whitespace left from the \strut command when aligning the label and title name, right?

@Atex Yes. \strut is more or less like \rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}. It fixes the text height in the nodes.
